# Implementing $n$-bit Toffoli gate with $(2n-5)$ and $(4n-12)$ CCNOT gates

Tags: circuit-construction, quantum-circuit

Papers such as [Diao et al. "A Quantum Circuit Design for Grover’s Algorithm"](https://doi.org/10.1515/zna-2002-0810) implement an $n-1$ bit Toffoli gate with $2n-7$ gates and $n-3$ scratch bits. I want to know if there is a way to implement it with $2n-5$ gates rather than $2n-7$. Perhaps some modification to the structure in Diao? Also, I noticed that $4n-12$ is just $2(2n-6)$, implying that there is some sort of compute-uncompute going on, but it looks like you don't need to uncompute for $4n-12$ gates?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking. Why are you trying to *increase* the number of Toffolis by 2 from 2n-7 to 2n-5? And where did 4n-12 even come from?